# MAUI - How to make a grid to fill the entire screen after rotating the grid?

Tags: maui

I have app that is using portrait orientation only. But I have page that need to be showed in landscaped orientation. I ddidn't change screen orientation but only rotated main grid. By default grid keeps original size, so it is a problem because height is much bigger that width.
I'm wondering how can I property set Width and Height for this grid to use whole screen of device.

Now I'm using hardcoded numeric values. It looks pretty ok on my phone, but it is worse on other devices.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="HelpMeHum.Maui.Pages.GamePages.PlayPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false">

    <Grid Rotation="90" x:Name="Grid"
        Margin="15,15,15,15"
        RowSpacing="5"
        WidthRequest="750" HeightRequest="350">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label
            x:Name="FirstLabel"
            FontSize="64"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            VerticalTextAlignment="End"
            Grid.Row="0" />

        <Label
            x:Name="SecondLabel"
            FontSize="40"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            VerticalTextAlignment="Start"
            Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Labels text is changed in runtime (it is changed multiple times).
In future I also want to add some buttons in left bottom corner, but I still want to have first label on top half of screen and second on bottom half.

Comment: I do not quite understand what you want to achieve.  What is the expected behavior and how does that differ from the actual behavior?

Comment: I just want the grid to fill the whole screen. Sometimes I have long text on labels and I don't want it to overflow over the edge of the screen. My actual solution works pretty well on Samsung A52, but when I install this app on Sony XZ1, the label width is too long.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to [Customize UI appearance based on the platform and device idiom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/customize-ui-appearance). It can help to customize UI on different device. For example:

```
 <Grid  x:Name="Grid" BackgroundColor="Yellow"
     WidthRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=750,Tablet=850,Desktop=950}"
     ...>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, but I was thinking about something totally different. I have a problem: on one phone it looks ok, but on the other one, it looks bad. Peter's solution with calculating size is nearly perfect.

Comment: May I ask if this issue has been solved?

Comment: I used Peter's solution with the stuff that I written in comments to his solution. Now this view looks pretty good, but still it could be better (I don't know how it would look on IPhones and on Android with gesture navigation bar there would be not used space).

Comment: You could raise a new thread on GitHub for your new question and let more people see and help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate the grid you need to set the height to 0, rotate and then set it to the width of the device. Try and see if this solves your problem.

This is an example of what I mean:

```cs
private void RotateGrid()
{
    var screenWidth = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width / DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density;

    var targetRotation = MyGrid.Rotation == 0 ? 90 : 0;

    if (targetRotation == 90)
    {
        MyGrid.HeightRequest = 0;
        MyGrid.RotateTo(targetRotation, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
        MyGrid.HeightRequest = screenWidth;
    }
    else
    {
        MyGrid.RotateTo(targetRotation, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly for Height, but there is a problem with Width. In the case of long text, part of it is hidden behind the navigation and status bar.
https://i.snipboard.io/YvVjia.jpg (I made one temporary change in xaml, I changed VerticalTextAlignment of FirstLabel to Start, and SecondLabel to End, just to check if it looks properly on edges of screen)

Comment: I found that StatusBar height is 24 and NavigationBar height is 48 on Android. I'm using these values to adjust grid width and it looks good on my phone. But IMO it still could be better, on Android could be enabled NavigationBar for gestures that is lower than standard.